# tabbed webbrowser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I would like to create the ability for a user to have opened more than one webbrowser instance in my windows phone application, but I have not been able to find any documentation explaning how this may be accomplished. To be more exact, I would like to mimick the tabbed browsing experience offerred by the default Windows Phone Internet Explorer application. A already have a single webbrowser isntance working correctly with navigation and whatnot, but how would I be able to add multiple 'tabbed' instances so each webbrowser instance may be on a seperate page simultaneously? ( I am relatively new to C# and Windows phone so any code, links, or detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated.) Thanks in advance!

my code is as follows:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <my:FullWebBrowser Name="TheBrowser" Grid.RowSpan="2" InitialUri="http://www.google.com" Height="800" Margin="0,0,0,-690" />

</Grid>
```

TabsPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
</Grid>


<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Icons/appbar.new.rest.png" IsEnabled="True" Text="new" x:Name="NewBtn" Click="NewBtn_Click"/>
                </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Right now TabsPage.xaml is blank except for an app bar icon which should allow for creation of a new webbrowser instance when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't create separate pages for the tabs, my first though is to create multiple browser controls on top of each other and show only the current tab's browser control.

EDIT:

Normally nobody would do this but I wrote a simple multi-tab browserlike app for you. It's very primitive, but you'll get the idea. Btw you should try harder to come up with a solution, this is really not hard... Here is the MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="UrlTextBox"
             KeyDown="UrlTextBox_KeyDown" />
    <Grid x:Name="BrowserHost"
          Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="1"
                                          Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="2"
                                          Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="3"
                                          Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="4"
                                          Click="TabMenuItem_Click" />
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Here is the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private const int NumTabs = 4;

    private int currentIndex;
    private string[] urls = new string[NumTabs];
    private WebBrowser[] browsers = new WebBrowser[NumTabs];

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowTab(0);
    }

    private void ShowTab(int index)
    {
        this.currentIndex = index;
        UrlTextBox.Text = this.urls[this.currentIndex] ?? "";
        if (this.browsers[this.currentIndex] == null)
        {
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            this.browsers[this.currentIndex] = browser;
            BrowserHost.Children.Add(browser);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NumTabs; i++)
        {
            if (this.browsers[i] != null)
            {
                this.browsers[i].Visibility = i == this.currentIndex ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UrlTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Uri url;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
            {
                this.urls[this.currentIndex] = UrlTextBox.Text;
                this.browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(url);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid url");
        }
    }

    private void TabMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Int32.Parse(((ApplicationBarMenuItem)sender).Text) - 1;
        ShowTab(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kylerrr I believe I understand what you are suggestiong but I have no idea how to implement that solution. I have edited my original post above to include more information, maybe you could help? How exactly would I create a new webbrowser control on TabsPage.xaml app bar button click event to display as a fresh browsing instance over the previous web browser control (and switch between each added control)? Could you possibly include some example code so that I may play around and examine your solution? Thanks again.

Comment: your edit definately helps me understand the correct process, I was unsure of how to best create the new instances of the browser depending upon the number of tabs open but it seems you solved that with a simple array of urls and webbrowser controls, and your showtab method was something I was having issues with as well. Thanks I appreciate you putting in terms I can understand, hopefully others will find your solution as beneficial as I have!

Comment: I was attemptnig to seperate your tabbed browsing sample into two seperate pages, one displaying the current browsing index (MainPage.xaml) and then another page controlling the creation and selection of the current browser isntance, but I am having trouble deciding how to pass data between the two pages to accomplish this? What would you suggest as the best way to seperate the logic between these two pages? I have placed most of the logic in the TabsPage.xaml and am attempting to show the chosen browser index on MainPage.xaml and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to use **"open in new tab"** method for the above post?